# Field not accessible within runAs() method in Test class

Tags: apex, unit-test, security

I am checking for field accessibility of an **User u** whose **Profile** is **p** in apex Test class.To this profile field level security is set to **Hidden** for the field **team_name__c**.When I run as this user using **runAs()** method, and check the field accessibility as below, it returns **false**.

```
System.runAs(u){
system.debug('Accessible---> '+Schema.SObjectType.MyCustomObject__c.fields.team_Name__c.isAccessible());
//prints false
}
```

But according to the doc

> The system method runAs enables you to write test methods that change
>   the user context to an existing user or a new user so that the user’s
>   record sharing is enforced. *The runAs method doesn’t enforce user
>   permissions or field-level permissions*, only record sharing.

Which means field should have been accessible to the User within runAs() method as it doesn't enforce field level permissions.Please correct me if my understanding is wrong.

Comment: Can you show us more code? Are you double sure the user have right profile? Also did you checked if this profile/user have anything that could oweride this access level?

Comment: @ArturKępczyński As I mentioned in my question the profile assigned to user has visibility Hidden to the field.

Comment: @ArturKępczyński:regarding more code,I am just setting up User and Profile objects and nothing else.

Comment: add @isTest(seealldata=true) annotation before test class defination, it may solve your problem

Comment: @user7067 Yup its there.My concern is, apex is considering field level permission of the running user, which should not have been according to my understanding of the above excerpt from the doc.

Comment: Some ancient history about platform bugs in this area https://developer.salesforce.com/forums?id=906F00000008xv9IAA. Later in the thread FLS problems are mentioned, and it sounds like the intention is that System.runAs should allow FLS to be tested.

Comment: @KeithC that means in the runAs() method FLS is enforced ?

Comment: That is how I read it, but those (the field level ones) are not comments from salesforce people so it is not definitive. And it sounds like the object-level bug (caching across test methods) may have been present in the field level case too and that may or may not have been fixed. Hopefully someone will answer your question with solid information about what they see today in the platform.

Comment: Important question here. Do you have `@isTest(seeAllData=true)` in your Test Class? That would affect the results of your schema query. The query would apply not just to your test data, but to All Data in the org which may be the source of the difference between what you expected to see and what what you're actually seeing.

Comment: @crmprogdev Yes, @isTest(seeAllData=true) annotation is marked in my class.But the schema query is within runAs() method, which according to the doc should not enforce FLS.

Answer (score 6):

Apex will not **enforce** CRUD and FLS no matter what you do -- but you can **test** for CRUD and FLS using the method you documented in your code sample.

You must write your own handling code to 'gracefully degrade' your app should the running user not have the appropriate (read, create, update, delete) on the object or field within the object.

I'm sure you've read these docs a dozen times, but I'm posting it here for completeness of the answer:

https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Testing_CRUD_and_FLS_Enforcement

https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Enforcing_CRUD_and_FLS

> developers should consider having graceful degradation within their
>   applications if appropriate for their design.

Comment: Nice answer! Note the exception of ExecAnon, which enforces CRUD and FLS :-)